# Given an array of values corresponding to the location of a leaf node, how would I access said node?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, tree, tree-nodes

Note: I am unfamiliar with terminology regarding tree structures. Please forgive any oversights that may be a result of my ignorance!

#### Practical Example

Given an array as such:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 8
    [3] => 9
)
```

The tree node with the key "9" would be found at `$tree[2][8][9]` (with 0 being the root). Given the above array, how would I construct a statement in PHP that would access the leaf node?

#### Target Code

```
/*
    Let's say I am given a $leafNodeID of 9, and I'd like to save some
    data ($dataToSave) into said leaf node
*/
$leafNodeID = 9;
$dataToSave = array("name" => "foobar");
$tree_path = $this->findPathToRootNode($tree, $leafNodeID);    // This returns the array found above.
${?????} = $dataToSave;     // <-- Here be dragons
```

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**: For those wondering, my `findPathToRootNode` function just recursively finds the parent node, and saves it in the array format found above. If there's a better way to represent said data (especially if it solves my problem), that would be even better.

**Edit**: On a read through, it seems this question is less about trees, but rather how to access an array given its structure in a separate array. Tagging as such.

Answer (score 0):

Make a self-targeting function. This should do the trick (untested)

```
function getLeaf($tree, $targetleaf, $depth = 0){
    if (isset($targetleaf[$depth+1])
        return getLeaf($tree[$targetleaf[$depth]], $targetleaf, $depth + 1)
    else
        return $tree[$depth];
}
```

With `$tree` being the data, `$tree` the path to the array, and `$depth` speaks for itself.

Call the function with

```
$leaf = getLeaf($tree,$targetleaf);
```

Comment: Cheers, Topener. I'll give it a try in the next couple days and report back.

Comment: Hi Topener - the solution looks good (although it didn't work exactly in my code for some reason). However, since the input is safe (pulled from database), I ended up just using eval, and commenting heavily around it. :)